calculate the terms of a function using base 2, number theory
I have the following problem from the book Teoria dos Numeros:um passeio com primos e outros numeros familiares pelo mundo inteiro.
Let $f : \mathbb{N} >0 → \mathbb{N}$ be a defined function of the set of integers
positive in the set of natural numbers such that
(a) $f(1) = 0$;
(b) $f(2n) = 2f(n) + 1$;
(c) $f(2n + 1) = 2f(n)$.
Use the base $2$ representation of $n$ to find a non-standard formula.
recursive for $f(n)$.
Doing small cases, one may notice that $f(2^k + x) = 2^k - x - 1$, with $x$ smaller than $2^k$. This is straightforward using strong induction, but I'm interested in using base $2$ (what the book asks). Does this simplify the problem in some way, and how can I write a solution using base $2$?

$f(2^k+x) = 2^k-x-1$ would be bit flips, of the lowest $k+1$ bits. Is this the "non-standard formula" you are looking for?

In terms of strings over the alphabet $\{0,1\},$ if $a_1=1$ then
$$f(a_1a_2\ldots a_n)=f(a_1a_2\ldots a_{n-1})(1-a_n)$$
where $f(\emptyset)=\emptyset.$
This resolves to
$$f(a_1a_2\ldots a_n)=\hbox{concat}_{i=1}^n(1-a_i)$$
